# ''$\Gamma\vdash A\ \textrm{true}$'' in Martin-Löf type theory

Tags: logic, type-theory, lambda-calculus

I have a basic question about the notation ''$\Gamma\vdash A\ \textrm{true}$'' in Martin-Löf type theory. In his 1984 book, Martin-Löf says that if we have $\Gamma\vdash a:A$ and we do not care about the computational content of the proof, we shall suppress $a$ writing simply $\Gamma\vdash A\ \textrm{true}$. My question is, what is ''true'' in this notation? Is ''true'' a type, or is it a meta-level label?

Comment: It is a meta-label. See page 2 (about **Propositions and judgments**): "When we hold a proposition $A$ to be true, we make a judgement: "proposition $A$ is true" is a judgement." Thus, to write "$\Gamma \vdash A \text { true}$" can be read as a judgment about the existence of a derivation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"$\Gamma \vdash A\text{ true}$" is a *judgment*, which we can read as "in the context $\Gamma$ the proposition $A$ is true".

You've already encountered another sort of judgment, "$\Gamma \vdash a : A$", which we normally read as "in the context $\Gamma$, the term $a$ has type $A$", or under the identification of propositions and types, "in the context $\Gamma$, the term $a$ proves the proposition $A$".

The label $\text{ true}$ belongs to the same syntactic category in the former judgment that the turnstile symbol "$\vdash$" and the colon symbol "$:$" belong to in the latter judgment. They form part of the *notation* that we use for writing judgments.

Comment: Thanks! So, how shall we formally express ''$A$ is true'' as a proposition but not as a judgment?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question about expressing "$A$ is true" as a proposition. Type theory (in its usual forms) does not allow one to treat judgment as propositions. E.g. one can negate a proposition, but it doesn't make sense to negate a typing judgment by writing $\neg (a : A)$ in type theory -- except possibly on the meta-level, where one would sometimes define something like $a \not : A$ as an abbreviation for the meta-level proposition "there is no derivation tree that concludes with the judgment $\vdash a : A$".

Comment: Okay, that's also what I see. Intuitively we can treat ''A is true'' as a proposition, for example, in ordinary discourse. But it appears to me that type theory does not allow us to express that.

Comment: That isn't how precise treatments of logic generally classify things, though. Propositions are things that may be affirmed or denied. The closest thing would be "$A = ⊤$", where $⊤$ is the vacuously true proposition. But this is redundant, and equivalent to just the proposition $A$. For instance, I wouldn't expect you to say "5 > 3 is true" is meant as something intended to be further decided true or false, because it's redundant. Rather, it's expressing a "judgment" that the proposition "5 > 3" is actually true. That is intention of the structure.